# How to extract only dialogues of a main character from a movie script

Tags: text-processing

I would like to build a corpus for movie scripts to analyze gender representation in film discourse. I would like to know a way to process .pdf or .txt format of movie scripts so that I can:

1. separate dialogues from scenes
2. extract only the dialogues of the main character (providing all names are in caps, and lines are separated by linebreak)

[image: here is a screenshot of the script]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Most such sources are written to a standard style that when extracted does not separate well unless you are a Thespian. this looks like an easy passage. but throughout the whole document there are often mixed case line with actor name.

The more normal layout will be almost as difficult to divide, but easier to detect, as a character is usually 27 spaces from the left. see previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71521583/10802527 however this example is not so regular except it is as converted to 0 spaces.

The structure should be possible to chunk by "RegEx" as the first line of a dialog is ALL CAPS (WITH. 1/SOME, OTHERS) and in general a space line for next SLUG or CHARACTER.

Therefore all you need to do is look for Lines that start with `MARGARET` then check to end of line has "no lower case" `MARGARET (V. O.)` will be acceptable just beware there might be `MARGARET (to DENIS)` unlike the example below, then export via redirect all text to next blank line.

The major issue is what format the output should be, so will leave that for others to ponder and answer more.

```
INT. KITCHEN. CHESTER SQUARE. LONDON. PRESENT. DAY.

MARGARET sits at breakfast with her husband DENIS, 
sipping tea. DENIS butters his toast. MARGARET shakes her 
head.

MARGARET
Too much. Much too much butter.

DENIS
I like butter.

MARGARET 
Milk’s gone up. 

MARGARET reaches for a jug, pouring milk into it, sliding 
it down on a table. 

MARGARET (CONT’D)
49p a pint.

DENIS 
Good grief! We’ll have to 
economise. I suppose we could 
always sell the car. 
(chuckles)
Or take in paying guests!

He scoops up the newspaper and glances towards the door -

DENIS (CONT'D)
Watch out. She’s on the prowl.

MARGARET looks beyond DENIS to a a sense of growing 
commotion. A concerned POLICE GUARD coming up the stairs 
meeting JUNE [early 60’s] MARGARET’s carer, along a 
distant corridor, steady on the approach.

MARGARET 
(to DENIS)
Eat your egg.
```